# Can't get a div to be 100% height

Tags: css, html

I've tried several suggestions online, making my html and body tags have a height of 100% as well as a min-height of 100%. I've set my div tag as the same as well.. It just isn't expanding to the bottom of the screen.

Also I can't get a second floating div to fill 100% of the space not filled up by another div beside it. It will only fill 100% of the screen (under the other smaller div) or enough to allow for the text.

I guess it should be noted that I tried viewing in IE9 as well as Firefox 16.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      overflow:hidden;
    }  
    div#topbar {
      width: 100%;
      height:133px;
      background-image :url(bkgnd_header_tile.jpg);
    }
    div#logo {
      width: 187px;
      height: 133px;
      background-image:url('headerlogo_home.jpg');
      float: left;
    }
    div#text {
      width: 1;
      height: 133px;
      float: right;
    }
    div#campuses {
      height: 68px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      color: White;
      text-align: right;
    }
    div#title {
      height: 41px;
      color: White;
      text-align: right;
      padding-top: 14px;
    }
    div#sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 250px;
      float: right;
      background-color: Black;
    }
    div#body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%
      float: right;
      font-family: Segoe UI;
    }
    span.text {
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      font-family: Sans-Serif;
      font-size: small;
    }
    span.name {
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      font-family: Sans-Serif;
      font-size: x-large;
    }  
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="text">
      <div id="campuses">
        <span class="text">St. John's Campus</span>
        <span class="text">Grenfell Campus</span>
        <span class="text">Marine Institute</span>
        <span class="text">Harlow Campus</span>
        <span class="text">Distance Education</span>
      </div>
      <div id="title"><span class="name">Memorial Self Service</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">

  </div>
  <div id="body">
    asdf</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help with this if we could see the HTML.

Comment: @sp00m I added the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, following Ravindra's suggestion, and modifying it a bit, I got this to work. I set the body with the following style settings

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

and used these for my two DIV sections:

```
div#body { 
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:scroll;
}

div#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color : #EFEFEF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#content {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 300px;
```

`<div id="body"></div>` is a parent container for the other two div's, id="sidebar" and id="content". I did this because I also had a top bar in its own div 133px high just above the "body" div.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `position:relative` to body will take body's height into account and stretch absolutely positioned content along body completely
Note that height property specified in percentage is calculated with the respect to the containing block

or you can also try `overflow:hidden;` in body tag

Comment: This didn't help either. I posted the HTML to see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the position to absolute as always I had these kind of weird behaviour, the absolute came to rescue, on top of that I would also set left and top to 0

Comment: That solves it for the div on the left, but I can't get it to work for the div on the right as well - I have a sidebar that also needs to extend to the bottom of the screen. If I set that as position: absolute, it moves to the left of the window.

Comment: try to define right:0px to that right div instead of left, with absolute